# Serving HTML content StreamSocketListener

Tags: c#, sockets, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, webserver

I'm trying to create a simple web server for a specific endpoint "/check" on my Windows Phone (8.1).

I've implemented the StreamSocketListener by following http://peted.azurewebsites.net/streamsocket-example-c-metro/

My main issue is how am I supposed to serve a HTML response to devices connecting to me?

Comment: You'd need to implement the HTTP protocol if you want to make web browsers work with it. But, if that's not it, then you need to invent your own protocol. It's just a socket where you decide how data flows.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://www.dzhang.com/blog/2012/09/18/a-simple-in-process-http-server-for-windows-8-metro-apps. It contains code for implementing a basic HTTP server using StreamSocketListener, returning files. Just modify it to return your html with correct mime type.

Comment: I have actually tried that and it didn't work for me.

Comment: can you be more specific?

Comment: I ran the application with a breakpoint on WinRT then tried accessing on chrome MYIP:PORT/foo.txt but nothing went through. The page just didn't connect.